# Excel - How to calculate percentage difference between two percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two columns, both percentages based on other calculations. I want to have a third column which shows the percentage difference between each of sets of figures.

So:
H128 is 9%
I128 is 9.84%

I want J128 to show the % difference between the two.

Column I is the actual number, column H is the 'should have' number. I want column I to show a plus or minus percentage based on whether it's higher or lower than the 'should have' number.

Any help greatly appreciated, I've checked loads of sites but keep coming up with numbers that don't seem to make sense - I'm not great with percentages.

For example, I do:

=H128/I128

which gives me a difference of 95%, which is clearly insane, unless I'm reading it all wrong.

I also do:

=(H128-I128)/I128

which gives me a difference of -5% which is closer, but still doesn't seem right, or is it?

Comment: This should work `=I128-H128`

Comment: A percentage is a fraction. There’s no such thing as a “fraction difference between two fractions”. You need to clarify what you want to know: How close to `H` is `I`? Or do you perhaps want to know how much “better” `I` would have to be to reach `H`? Unless both fractions have the *same* denominator, there is no meaningful difference.

Comment: Are you interested in the absolute difference or relative difference, and what are the numbers of interest?  (End - Start) gives you the absolute difference.  (End - Start)/Start gives you the relative difference.  Are you working with the percentage numbers or the original values the percentages relate to?  The only way to answer your question would be to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi folks,

It's to work out the difference between 'x' and 'z'. So last year we had 9%, this year we have 9.84%, and I need to show the difference in percentage between the two. The figures just look crazy.

I also then need to put this into a graph, and the boss wants the difference shown at the top of each bar on the bar chart. I can get it showing on the bottom as a data table, but I can't figure a way of doing this without having to show that actual bar as well, which mucks the table up.

Comment: Please ask in the Statistics forum [Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) whether taking percentage of percentage difference is a meaningful way of Statistical Analysis.

Comment: @Kilm: In your example (it was 9%, now it's 9.84%), what is the difference that you would like to see? +0.84, given by 9.84-9? Or +9.33%, given by 0.84/9*100? Give us the number that you expect to see as result, then we can help. Otherwise we are left wondering what you mean by "difference".

Comment: Please have a look at this [http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/h/other1.html] (What is the percentage difference between 64.24% and 74.24%).

Comment: @Kilm: When you say last year you had 9%, this year 9.84%, where do those percentages come from?  What compared to what yields 9% and 9.84%?  What is the underlying activity that is being measured?  That context may provide a clue to what would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, Sorry for the error, when you click on the link ']' is getting added. Please delete it. Or Google "What is the percentage difference between 64.24% and 74.24%?".Here is the link again (http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/h/other1.html)